# Angular - Property 'results' does not exist on type 'IStudent[]'

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I want to display details of selected student from single column in a modal:

API JSON endpoint:

The list gives:

```js
{
  "message": "Students successfully Retrieved.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "students": [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Afam",
        "middle_name": "O",
        "last_name": "Kosi",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Akudo",
        "middle_name": "J",
        "last_name": "Lamptey",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For the detail of the row I want to select I have:

```js
{
  "message": "Student Detail.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "student": [{
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Afam",
      "middle_name": "O",
      "last_name": "Kosi",
    }]
  }
}
```

I have this Interface (IStudent):

```js
export interface IStudent {
  id ? : number;
  first_name: string;
  middle_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}
```

Then service:

```js
import {
  IStudent
} from 'src/app/models/student.model';

public getAllStudents(): Observable < any > {
  return this.http.get(this.api.baseURL + 'students/list', this.httpOptions);
}

getStudentById(id: number): Observable < IStudent[] > {
  return this.http.get < IStudent[] > (this.api.baseURL + 'students/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Then HTML and Component:

```html
<ng-template #actionTpl let-row let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columnValue="columnValue">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="viewStudent(row)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewStudentModal">
                        View
                      </a>&nbsp;
</ng-template>


<div class="modal fade" id="viewStudentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-name">First Name</label>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-name">Midle Name</label>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-name">Last Name</label>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hide()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From above, as the user clicks on the select row, viewStudent(row) from the student list it displays the view detail modal and also points to this component below:

```
import { IStudent } from 'src/app/models/student.model'; 
import { StudentService } from 'src/app/services/student.service'; 

studentDetail!: IStudent; 

constructor( private studentService: StudentService, private router: Router, ) { } 

viewStudent(row: any) {
 this.studentService.getStudentById(row).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.studentDetail = data.results.student;
  },
  error => {
    this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
  }
 );
}
```

It suppose to fetch the detail of the row of the selected student, but I got this error:

> Property 'results' does not exist on type 'IStudent[]'

and this is highlighted   data.results.student

When I did:

```
viewStudent(row: any) {
   console.log(row);
}
```

I got:

student: {id: 1, first_name: "Afam", middle_name: "O", last_name: "Kosi"}

How do I rsolve this error in order to display the detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your sample of response, your API response isn't just a `Student` but  an `object` that contains an array of `IStudent`. So, to mimic this, you can have something like:

```js
export interface IStudent {
  id?: number;
  first_name: string;
  middle_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}

export interface Results { // random name
  student: IStudent[];
}

export interface StudentResponse { // random name
  message: string;
  error: boolean;
  code: number;
  results: Results;
}
```

and so in your `getStudentById`:

```js
getStudentById(id: number): Observable<StudentResponse> {
  return this.http.get<StudentResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'students/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Note that if you only care about the `Student`, you can do something like this in `getStudentById`:

```js
getStudentById(id: number): Observable<IStudent> {
  return this.http.get<StudentResponse>(this.api.baseURL + 'students/fetchbyid/' + id, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(({ results: { 0: student }}) => student),
  );
}
```

Comment: Kindly allow me to ask this question. How do I now present or write this in the component in order to display on the HTML:   viewStudent(row: any) {
  ...
}

Comment: Excuse me, I don't get your question... To be clear, I answered about the Typescript types part, so you can present any data as you are doing currently, but without type errors. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Everything was going fine until when I got this error in the component:      Type 'IStudent[]' has no properties in common with type 'IStudent'.    and  this.studentDetail is highlighted in       this.studentDetail = data.results.student;

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?